# landscape mode border image in edittext not working

Tags: android, layout

you can refer to [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/changing-background-color-and-border-color-of-an-edittext-widget-using-state-list-in-android/) code.

Border color of Edit Text is set to some color.
working fine in portratait mode.
Why i can't see the same color/image in landsacpe mode??In landscape mode when soft key is open then edit text color become red(default)..where can i locate that red border scalable image??
 ny idea??

below is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit1_text"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit2_text"
        android:inputType="text"   
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"

        />


</LinearLayout>
```

and here is @drawable/edit_text file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />     
    <item 
        android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_pressed" />
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true" 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_selected" />     
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />    
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_selected" />    
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" /> 
</selector>
```

Comment: post some image and point the problem in that

Comment: images are present @ that link ..on landscape mode border image is not visible

Comment: Images int that link show edit text in landscape mode with border. please post images of your code here, with some code what have you done

Comment: [portrait mode image](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/custom_edit_text_screenshot.png)

Comment: @abhinav -  in lanscape mode that border is missin.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya - koi idea bro ?

Answer (score 0):

@Mr.Singh - When I executed your code in my device, I am getting edit text border even in landscape mode.Please check....

Comment: ya I tested on ICS and even on emulator(API 10)

Comment: in landsacpe mode ...try to input some text there...then see the border

Comment: @Mr.Singh - please check your mail

Comment: ![Landscape EditText border image](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1fqlLq6EokjuyiE1u9FAAPhQXbnnJZHHBPw8BRRUyT2Y/edit).

Comment: thnx... but still i din get the answr...i tried adding drawable-land-hdpi  layout-land-hdpi  folder also